# How to cache a local file as a external url

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I need to upload some file and load the file local and immediately cache that file as an external URL, for example, my endpoint is POST, api/v1/user/picture, but that need some seconds to be process by Amazon . I need to clean the cache and force to load my new "api/v1/user/picture" with my own local file. I'm trying to do this:

```
DiscCacheUtil.removeFromCache("file://"+path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());
MemoryCacheUtil.removeFromCache("file://" + path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
Log.d(TAG, "url: " + Uri.parse(url).toString()); // -> api/v1/user/picture 

DiscCacheUtil.removeFromCache(Uri.parse(url).toString(), ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());
MemoryCacheUtil.removeFromCache(Uri.parse(url).toString(), ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500, true, false, false)).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_seahorse).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_seahorse).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_seahorse).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file://" + path, userProfileImage, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ((ImageView) view).setImageDrawable(new RoundedAvatarDrawable(loadedImage));
        }
    }
});

ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().put(url, new File(path));
ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache().put(MemoryCacheUtil.generateKey(url,new ImageSize(userProfileImage.getWidth(), userProfileImage.getHeight())), BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
```

But doesn't works :( any help?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but instead of using `"file:///"+path`, try with `Uri.fromFile(new File(path))`